# Scrapy crawler for single website can't follow redirects

Tags: python-2.7, redirect, web-crawler, scrapy

I have a Scrapy crawler that takes a URL as argument and scrapes the entire website that URL points to, following *only* links to its other pages, thus ignoring external URLs.

For example, if URL = "http://mypage.com" and at that page they have two links, "http://mypage.com/about" and "http://google.com", only the first link is visited because it's in the same domain.

The way I do this is by setting  *allowed_domains = start_urls*.

However, one limitation of this approach is that if the URL is a redirect and I am redirected to another domain, then all URLs will be considered from an external domain given my implementation.

For example, in a situation where *start_urls = ["http://mypage.com"]* and *allowed_domains =
["http://mypage.com"]*, the spider starts at "http://mypage.com" and from there is redirected to "http://mypg.us", the spider will consider all the links of the new domain as external and stop crawling them.

I think it's highly likely that Scrapy has a setting for this, but I can't find. I am also open to changes in my implementation, though.